# Phone interrupted during update

Tags: updates, samsung, samsung-kies

I was updating my phone using Kies and the download was interrupted. My phone now has a black screen with a little phone, a yellow triangle with an exclamation point, and a computer on it. I cannot put the phone into recovery mode, and the Kies application has a little icon on it that says "emergency recovery" but when I click on it I then get a message that says

> TODO: has stopped working.  A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program.

I called Samsung, but they were no help at all. Their representative didn't even know what icon I was talking about. She just suggested that I take the battery out or try to put my phone in recovery mode, even though I kept explaining I already tried those things.

Comment: what phone is it?

Comment: What phone you have is important, you may be able to use Odin to fix this.  Sometimes Samsung phones do get "stuck" in Download Mode however, so I would try a combination of battery pulls with the device plugged into USB or not, while holding various buttons, etc. (basically as many combinations as you can think of).  Leaving the battery out for a couple hours before trying again might also help.

Comment: Make sure the battery is fully charged at least 90% charged... why was the download interrupted? Kies is notorious for this, if running something else, it throws Kies off during the update process... just saying, really, Kies is a terrible terrible piece of kit for this, you run into more risks of soft-bricking (did experience a hard-brick myself) in comparison to using Odin or Multitool flasher...

Answer (score -3):

You can try taking it to third-party repair shop. It might work better than Samsung as they do not care if you voided your warranty or not.